# Vim: Sort lines by text at position

Tags: vim

I'd like to use the vim sort command to start sorting at a certain position.
Without installing any plugins.

```
2011-09-17  00:37 |Free|ALL RIGHT NOW
2011-09-17  00:41 |Kim Wilde|CAMBODIA
2011-09-17  00:45 |Take That|NEVER FORGET
2011-09-17  00:53 |Visage|FADE TO GREY
2011-09-17  00:56 |SUTHERLAND BROTHERS & QUIVER|ARMS OF MARY
```

The command  `:sort u` starts at position 1.

In the example the artist name starts at position 20, so I'd like to start sorting there.

This is the result I'd like to get

```
2011-09-17  00:37 |Free|ALL RIGHT NOW
2011-09-17  00:41 |Kim Wilde|CAMBODIA
2011-09-17  00:56 |SUTHERLAND BROTHERS & QUIVER|ARMS OF MARY
2011-09-17  00:45 |Take That|NEVER FORGET
2011-09-17  00:53 |Visage|FADE TO GREY
```

Is this something easily done without plugins or should not attempt that?
Google spits out a lot of user defined scripts, but nothing working out of the box...

Comment: not exactly 20th position, but you could use external sort command.. for ex: `:%!sort -t'|' -k2` or `:%!sort -k3`

Comment: @Sundeep yes, but that requires the sort command line tool, which is not available on every operating system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of the box, you can sort starting at a virtual column

```
:sort /\%20v/
```

from `:help :sort`

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the first part of the line (until the "|" char) in your sort by the VIM command:

```
:sort /^[^|]*/
```

Comment: That works for the example, but don't answer the position 20 question. (I also plan to use that on text with a lot of pipes or no pipes at all and just fixed length fields) . If I'm going the regex-way, it may work with `.{20}*' to skip the first 20 chars, but I can't guess the syntax...

Comment: As a follow up, trying `:sort /^.{19}/` did not do anything.

Comment: Tried some more, I have to unexcape the `{`. The command `sort /^.\{19\}/` works..., not very elegant, though...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to sort from position 20, use the next syntax:

```
:sort /^.\{19}/
```

Mind the *backslash* before the opening bracket and the character to be repeated must be *before* the quantifier.